# How to get the exception message from Jenkins pipeline failure?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a `try { } catch (e) { }` block in my pipeline which will update the commit status in GitHub to indicate whether the build passed or failed. I'd like to extend the functionality to provide more details as to why the build failed. I'm using `e.localizedMessage` as the exception message right now but am not getting anything useful beyond `script returned exit code 1`.

Is there a different method or attribute to use to get the full exception message? Maybe the `stderr`?

For example, if I run

```
sh("ls nonexistentfolder")
```

I'd like to capture in my exception `e` the message

```
ls: nonexistentfolder: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What are you running in your shell script?

Comment: Updated with an example

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by saving stderr to a file and reading the file in catch block.

```
try{
    sh script: "ls nonexistentfolder 2>error.log"
}
catch(e){
    println(readFile('error.log').trim())
}
```